# JAVA Excel POI API: formulas not updated

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using the Java POI package to access the excel files. I have an excel file for which I am updating the cell values. those values are being used in some other sheets (within the same excel file) however, when I open the file, those values don't updated. when I select the cell text and hit enter then all the remaining sheets get the value.

Please suggest if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You need evaluate the formulas to update it's values.
check out here:

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html